I want the body to use the maximum height of the screen
My HTML has a header div and a body div.
I want the body div to grow to the maximum height of the screen.
If I set the height to 100vh, it worked but ignored the header div height.
So a scrollbar appears. I do not want a scrollbar.


html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
}

.body {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* for visualization purpose only */

.header {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.body {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
<body>
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="body">body</div>
</body>



current result
You can check my codepen: https://codepen.io/sforest1975/pen/YzMaEQO
I want the body div to be maximum height of the screen, but without scrollbar and not over 100% of the screen height.
Expected result:

I do not want to set the height of header, if possible.
I do not want to use px because different results may occur by font-size or browser.

First of all, use semantic tags instead of classes. It improves readability, accessibility, and with that your SEO rating. You have semantic tags such as header  and main.
Here is a quick list of things that need to be done to meet your requirements:

You need to reset the default box-sizing to border-box to take paddings and border thickness into account when calculating the height of an element.
You need to remove the default margin of the body and replace it with padding.
You need to apply min-height: 100vh to the body to let it span a minimum of the screen height.
You can let the "body" (actually a main element) take the entire remaining eight by using flex-grow: 1



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* for visualisation only */
header,
main {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <main>body</main>
</body>




thank you for your answer.  this is incredible simple.  i do  not know why i can't solve this. and sorry for duplicate question.
